# HTML range element vertical position difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS styling problem: there is a difference between Firefox and Chrome browsers in the CSS styling on an HTML element.

The **range** element is displayed on a different height in Firefox than in Chrome. I have added two screenshots.

**Firefox:**
[image]

**Chrome:**
[image]

The range element in Chrome is pressed against the upper edge of the "content" div. And in Firefox there is a small space between the range element and the upper edge of the "content" div - as shown by the red mark.

How can I set the **range** element to the same height in both Firefox and Chrome? In other words: I want the **range** element to be vertically in the center of the "content" div.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
 ...
 <div id="content">
  <input type="range" id="bar" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 640px;
    height: 372px;
    background: #000;
    margin: auto;
}

#content {
    width: 625px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to style `<input type="range">` properly on all browsers you need to do a lot

**1. you need to hide a lot of default browser styles**

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
  width: 100%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
  background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. You should probably do some kind of focus styling for accessibility reasons though. */
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;

  /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
  background: transparent; 
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

**2. then you need to style the track**

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #367ebd;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2a6495;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3071a9;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}
```

**3. then you need to style the thumb**

```
    /* Special styling for WebKit/Blink */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -14px; /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; /* Add cool effects to your sliders! */
}

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* All the same stuff for IE */
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

sorry copy and paste this - i edited it, now it should work

Comment: Tried it, but there is still a difference in the height of the  <input type="range"/>  element  in Firefox and Chrome. I need that element to be on the same height, that is: vertically in the center of the "content" div.

Comment: No the height still does not change. I have added a <!DOCTYPE html> tag to the top of the HTML page, now the range element in Chrome is displayed lower than the range element in Firefox. In Firefox it's still not displayed vertically in the center of the gray div.